# SQL: IN condition from array

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

The best way I can describe my problem is by giving you an example of my problem:

I have a table called "*person*" with the columns `id | name | hobbys`

`hobbys` would be a **manyToMany** association

So I have this statement: `SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN hobbys h ON p.hobby_id = h.id WHERE p.hobby_id IN($array);`

The problem here is, it will select all persons that have one of the hobbys in that array, but I want the selected persons MUST have all of the hobbys in that array.
Is there a function in sql?

Comment: ANSI SQL has no such function. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN hobbys h ON p.hobby_id = h.id WHERE p.hobby_id =
 ALL ($array);`
Try it Yourself, I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM person p 
JOIN hobbys h ON p.hobby_id = h.id 
WHERE p.hobby_id IN($array)
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING count(distinct h.id) = <size_of_array>
```

There are also other solutions using `INTERSECTION`, `IN`, or `EXISTS` however this one will keep the list of values behind `IN`.

Comment: ok. what if i got 2 tables like hobbys and other_hobbys
then this code wouldnt work.
i would sum() both column id's and check it with the size of the array. Unfortunatly that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have to search each item hobby in person and match them with a AND conjunction with all contents in hobby table

first, You have to get all records persons have in hobby

```
SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN hobbys h ON p.hobby_id = h.id
```

Now build the AND conditional statement, and later query it with

```
SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN hobbys h ON p.hobby_id = h.id 
WHERE first_result IN($array) and second_result in ($array) and....;
```